# Hibernate lazy initialization not working with Jackson Mapper

Tags: json, jackson, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I am using Spring 4 and Hibernate 4. I am using java jpa to use hibernate. I want to load few data lazily. And I have also configured Jackson mapper to convert my java object to json and vice versa. But it's throwing exception while converting the java to json. I have created custom object mapper but still it's not working.

Please see the following classes and see what I am missing here

I am using annotations. Hibernate configuration file:
MvcConfiguration.java

```
    package com.ampdev.platform.module.common.config;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.ampdev.platform.framework.dataaccess.config.HibernateAwareObjectMapper;
import com.ampdev.platform.framework.rest.security.AuthenticationService;
import com.ampdev.platform.framework.rest.security.AuthenticationServiceDefault;
import com.ampdev.platform.module.user.util.EncryptionUtil;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ampdev")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "authenticationService")
    public AuthenticationService getAuthencticaionService()
    {
        return new AuthenticationServiceDefault();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "encrypyionUtil")
    public EncryptionUtil getEncryptionUtil(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
    {
        return new EncryptionUtil(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "objectMapper")
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper()
    {
        return new HibernateAwareObjectMapper();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "jsonMessageConverter")
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter getMessageConvertor()
    {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
    {
        jsonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(jsonMessageConverter);
    }

}
```

I have created a custom object mapper to include Hibernate4Module
HibernateAwareObjectMapper.java

```
package com.ampdev.platform.framework.dataaccess.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module;

public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4013528320937607847L;

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper()
    {
        Hibernate4Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate4Module();
        registerModule(hibernateModule);
    }

}
```

Here is my Data object in which I am using the lazy loading:
UserMovieReviewData .java

```
package com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.review.user.dataobject;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import com.ampdev.platform.module.common.dataobject.PersistedDataObject;
import com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.dataobject.MovieData;
import com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.review.constants.ReviewConstants;
import com.ampdev.platform.module.user.dataobject.UserData;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@Entity
@Table(name = "movie_review_user")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserMovieReviewData extends PersistedDataObject
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5644749600929596177L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "review_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    private MovieData movieData;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserData userData;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private int rating;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "review")
    private String review;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createDate;

    @Column(name = "update_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updateDate;

    @Override
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MovieData getMovieData()
    {
        return movieData;
    }

    public void setMovieData(MovieData movieData)
    {
        this.movieData = movieData;
    }

    public UserData getUserData()
    {
        return userData;
    }

    public void setUserData(UserData userData)
    {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public int getRating()
    {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating)
    {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getReview()
    {
        return review;
    }

    public void setReview(String review)
    {
        this.review = review;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate()
    {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate)
    {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate()
    {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate)
    {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

}
```

Here is my web service resource which I am using as rest resource:
ReviewResource.java

```
package com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.review.resource;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.ampdev.platform.framework.rest.BaseExecutor;
import com.ampdev.platform.framework.rest.RestBaseResource;
import com.ampdev.platform.module.common.constants.URIConstants;
import com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.review.constants.ReviewConstants;
import com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.review.user.dataobject.UserMovieReviewData;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/ws/movie/review")
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ReviewResource extends RestBaseResource
{

    @Autowired
    private BaseExecutor<UserMovieReviewData, UserMovieReviewData> createMovieReviewExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private BaseExecutor<String, List<UserMovieReviewData>> getMovieReviewExecutor;

    @RequestMapping(value = ReviewConstants.ADD, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<UserMovieReviewData> createMovieReview(
        @RequestParam(value = ReviewConstants.TYPE, required = true) String type,
        RequestEntity<UserMovieReviewData> requestEntity)
    {
        createMovieReviewExecutor.setAttribute(ReviewConstants.TYPE, type);
        return performTask(requestEntity, createMovieReviewExecutor);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = URIConstants.GET_IDS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserMovieReviewData>> getReview(
        @RequestParam(value = ReviewConstants.TYPE, required = true) String type, @PathVariable(value = "ids") String reviewIds)
    {
        getMovieReviewExecutor.setAttribute(ReviewConstants.TYPE, type);
        getMovieReviewExecutor.setAttribute(ReviewConstants.REVIEW_IDS, reviewIds);
        return performTask(null, getMovieReviewExecutor);
    }

}
```

I am using spring 4 + hibernate 4.

I am getting the following error when I am trying to get data from Rest web service call:

```
I am getting the following error when I am trying to fetch the data from Rest web service:

    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:144)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

**root cause**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.review.user.dataobject.UserMovieReviewData[&quot;movieData&quot;]-&gt;com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.dataobject.MovieData_$$_jvst49f_5[&quot;id&quot;])
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:187)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:652)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1837)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

**root cause**

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    com.ampdev.platform.module.movie.dataobject.MovieData_$$_jvst49f_5.getId(MovieData_$$_jvst49f_5.java)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:726)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:506)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1837)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I am trying to fetch the data from Rest web service:

Answer (score 1):

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`

You're trying to access a lazy collection outside of the hibernate session. There are a few ways to solve this, the most clear is to access the `size()` of each collection you're going to be serializing in your service class, which causes the collection to be loaded and therefore available outside the session.

Another alternative is to annotate the collection with `FetchType.EAGER`, but this will affect all uses of your model, which might not be what you want. Finally, you can use the `OpenSessionInView` pattern, which maintains an open hibernate session for the duration of the request (and therefore allows you to load lazy collections outside where the session boundary would otherwise be). This last alternative is generally considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot for the answer. But the desired behavior what I want to achieve is if it's lazily initialized and so I don't want to include it in my JSON response. I want to include it in JSON response only when it's loaded (not null). So I was trying to customize the ObjectMapper to achieve this but I am failing to do that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, with `jackson-datatype-hibernate`, you need to set the feature `FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` to false in order to serialize non-loaded lazy collections as nulls.

Comment: [See here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-hibernate/javadoc/h4-2.4/)